# How to get determinant progress bar with progress update for downloading file using retrofit, kotlin coroutine Deferred call using MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

How to get determinant progress bar with progress update for downloading pdf file from url link using retrofit.
I am using kotlin coroutine Deferred call method using MVVM pattern.

I have tried with asynctask its working well but I don't find any option to get this using kotlin coroutine Deferred call method with Retrofit call.